# How did Dumbledore discover Voldemort's Cave?

Tags: harry-potter

I know that Dumbledore may have considered Voldemort’s past as an orphan and his activities as suspicious. Dumbledore may have even guessed that Voldemort associated the bullying of children as Voldemort’s first triumph over Muggles. But how exactly did Dumbledore discover the cave? He couldn’t have gone back to the orphanage since the orphanage was demolished and replaced by an office building.

Answer (score 11):

Mrs. Cole at the orphanage let slip that there was a sea cave near where the orphans were taken on summer vacationL:

> ‘But I’m jiggered if I know how he got up there to do it. All I know is he and Billy had argued the day before. And then –’ Mrs Cole took another swig of gin, slopping a little over her chin this time, ‘on the summer outing – we take them out, you know, once a year, to the countryside or to the seaside – well, Amy Benson and Dennis Bishop were never quite right afterwards, and all we ever got out of them was that they’d gone into a cave with Tom Riddle. He swore they’d just gone exploring, but something happened in there, I’m sure of it. And, well, there have been a lot of things, funny things ...’
>   She looked at Dumbledore again, and though her cheeks were flushed, her gaze was steady.
>   <sub>*Half-Blood Prince* - page 251 - Bloomsbury - chapter thirteen, *The Secret Riddle*</sub>

Dumbledore spent much of *Half-Blood Prince* going off and looking for Horcruxes. Knowing Tom Riddle had used a sea cave to terrify his fellow orphans gave him a clue to at least start looking for appropriate sea caves. And eventually he found the right one:

> ‘Lumos,’ said Dumbledore, as he reached the boulder closest to the cliff face. A thousand flecks of golden light sparkled upon the dark surface of the water a few feet below where he crouched; the black wall of rock beside him was illuminated too.
>   ‘You see?’ said Dumbledore quietly, holding his wand a little higher.
>   Harry saw a fissure in the cliff into which dark water was swirling.
>   <sub>*Half-Blood Prince* - page 520 - Bloomsbury - chapter twenty-six, *The Cave*</sub>

This is when Dumbledore and Harry find the sea cave. Dumbledore also senses that the cave has known magic and determines Tom Riddle had once been there.

> ‘How did you know that was there?’ Harry asked in astonishment.
>   ‘Magic always leaves traces,’ said Dumbledore, as the boat hit the bank with a gentle bump, ‘sometimes very distinctive traces. I taught Tom Riddle. I know his style.’
>   <sub>*Half-Blood Prince* - page 527 - Bloomsbury - chapter twenty-six, *The Cave*</sub>

Comment: I should note that when Harry says, "How did you know that was there?" he was referring to the chain and boat to cross the lake in the cave, not the cave itself. I included that passage for the "Magic leaves traces" bit. Just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 7):

Dumbledore was looking for it for quite a while (see my third quote where he says that straight out); he had clues as to it's general location from his original interviews at the orphanage, but not a lot of specifics.

From Half Blood Prince:

> All I know is he and Billy had argued the day before. And then” — Mrs. Cole took another swig of gin, slopping a little over her chin this time — “on the summer outing — we take them out, you know, once a year, to the countryside or to the seaside — well, Amy Benson and Dennis Bishop were never quite right afterwards, and all we ever got out of them was that they’d gone into a cave with Tom Riddle. He swore they’d just gone exploring, but something happened in there, I’m sure of it.

Dumbledore references it shortly after:

> The little stories of the strangled rabbit and the young boy and girl he lured into a cave were most suggestive. … ‘I can make them hurt if I want to. …’ ”

Then, later, he indicates that he's found it after much searching:

> “Which Horcrux is it? Where is it?”
>   “I am not sure which it is — though I think we can rule out the snake — but I believe it to be hidden in a cave on the coast many miles from here, a cave I have been trying to locate for a very long time: the cave in which Tom Riddle once terrorized two children from his orphanage on their annual trip; you remember?”

He most likely found it by researching where the children were taking on outings, and then searching from there for locations that would have been logical extensions of the trips, as well as fitting in to the description:

> “They brought the kids from the orphanage here?” asked Harry, who could not imagine a less cozy spot for a day trip.
>   “Not here, precisely,” said Dumbledore. “There is a village of sorts about halfway along the cliffs behind us. I believe the orphans were taken there for a little sea air and a view of the waves.

His research methods are never show directly 'on camera', but we've seen him use a number of tactics to find other information (such as other Horcruxes.)  Even with the Orphanage burned down, there were many sources of data he could have accessed, since he knew roughly what he was looking for -- centralized records, memories of others who worked or lived there, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Dumbledores discovery of the cave was due to him hearing the story of tom taking children down to a cave. Dumbledore has shown he has an excellent memory so remembering that is a non-issue. So when searching for horrocrux's dumbledore most likely went to the orphanage first, found it was no longer there, proceeded to go to the next best place, the cave. Dumbledore also shows he can sense magic something that no other wizard is shown the do (other then assumably Voldemort since he set up the cave) so once he found the cave it was simple to realize it was in fact the correct cave.

> ‘How did you know that was there?’ Harry asked in
>   astonishment.
>   ‘Magic always leaves traces,’ said Dumbledore, as the boat
>   hit the bank with a gentle bump, ‘sometimes very distinctive
>   traces. I taught Tom Riddle. I know his style.’

Answer (score 0):

Just pay attention when Dumbledore visits Tom in the orphanage, you will see there is a small picture which was fixed on the wall and in the picture you see the sea and the cave (the same location of the horcrux).

Comment: Is there any evidence that Dumbledore saw that photo?

Comment: That doesn't explain how he learned about it in the novels.